# Qwt axis don't displayed properly

Tags: qt, arm, cross-compiling, qwt

Qt version: 5.2.1
Qwt version: 6.1.0
Application: tvplot example (bug is the same for all other examples with graphs and axis)
Host platform: x64
Target platform: arm-linux-gnueabi
Problem: please take a look to attached picture - both axis don't displayed properly, there is only few labels instead of full set of marks and labels.
Maybe the reason is contained in Qt/Qwt configuration? How can I fix these axis?
[image]

My qmake.conf:

```
MAKEFILE_GENERATOR      = UNIX
CONFIG                 += incremental gdb_dwarf_index
QMAKE_INCREMENTAL_STYLE = sublib

include(../common/linux.conf)
include(../common/gcc-base-unix.conf)
include(../common/g++-unix.conf)

# modifications to g++.conf
QMAKE_CC                = arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
QMAKE_CXX               = arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
QMAKE_LINK              = arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB        = arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
QMAKE_CFLAGS        += -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -O3
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS      += $$QMAKE_CFLAGS

QMAKE_LIBDIR        += /home/uki/tslib-master/src/.libs/
QMAKE_INCDIR        += /home/uki/tslib-master/src/

QMAKE_LIBS      += -licui18n -licuuc -licudata

# modifications to linux.conf
QMAKE_AR                = arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar cqs
QMAKE_OBJCOPY           = arm-none-linux-gnueabi-objcopy
QMAKE_NM                = arm-none-linux-gnueabi-nm -P
QMAKE_STRIP             = arm-none-linux-gnueabi-strip
load(qt_config)
```

My Qt configuration line:

```
./configure -prefix /opt/qt-5.2.1/ -xplatform linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -release -opensource -confirm-license \
    -no-c++11 -shared -accessibility -no-pch -no-largefile \
    -qpa linuxfb -linuxfb -no-audio-backend -no-javascript-jit \
    -qt-zlib -qt-libjpeg -qt-libpng -qt-freetype -qt-pcre -no-opengl -verbose \
    -nis -no-cups -no-dbus -no-avx -no-glib -tslib -icu \
    -I /home/uki/icu-cross/source/common/ -I /home/uki/icu-cross/source/i18n/ -I /home/uki/icu-cross/source/io/ \
    -L /home/uki/icu-cross/source/lib
```

My qwtconfig.pri:

```
QWT_VER_MAJ      = 6
QWT_VER_MIN      = 1
QWT_VER_PAT      = 0
QWT_VERSION      = $${QWT_VER_MAJ}.$${QWT_VER_MIN}.$${QWT_VER_PAT}

QWT_INSTALL_PREFIX = $$[QT_INSTALL_PREFIX]

unix {
    QWT_INSTALL_PREFIX    = /usr/local/qwt-$$QWT_VERSION
}

win32 {
    QWT_INSTALL_PREFIX    = C:/Qwt-$$QWT_VERSION
}

QWT_INSTALL_DOCS      = $${QWT_INSTALL_PREFIX}/doc
QWT_INSTALL_HEADERS   = $${QWT_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include
QWT_INSTALL_LIBS      = $${QWT_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib

QWT_INSTALL_PLUGINS   = $${QWT_INSTALL_PREFIX}/plugins/designer

#QWT_INSTALL_PLUGINS   = $$[QT_INSTALL_PREFIX]/plugins/designer

QWT_INSTALL_FEATURES  = $${QWT_INSTALL_PREFIX}/features
# QWT_INSTALL_FEATURES  = $$[QT_INSTALL_PREFIX]/features

QWT_CONFIG           += QwtDll

QWT_CONFIG       += QwtPlot

QWT_CONFIG     += QwtWidgets

QWT_CONFIG     += QwtSvg

#QWT_CONFIG     += QwtOpenGL

#QWT_CONFIG     += QwtMathML

#QWT_CONFIG     += QwtDesigner

win32 {
    QWT_CONFIG     += QwtDesignerSelfContained
}

#QWT_CONFIG     += QwtExamples

#QWT_CONFIG     += QwtPlayground

macx:!static:CONFIG(qt_framework, qt_framework|qt_no_framework) {

    QWT_CONFIG += QwtFramework
}
```